# Devise_token_auth - unable to run controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, devise, token, alamofire

I am currently building an iOS app which communicates with a ruby-on-rails api. The user management(sign_in, sign_out,...) part of the api is handled with `devise_token_auth` gem.

I am also using `Alamofire` to run `HTTP` requests.

I am currently testing two apis:

1. `POST   /api/auth/sign_in(.:format)          devise_token_auth/sessions#create`
2. `POST   /api/posts(.:format)                 api/posts#create`

The first api is used to login while the second creates posts. FYI, in my `posts_controller`, I am using `before_action :authenticate_user!` to prevent non authenticated users to create posts.

Here is what I want to do:

1. Sign in from the client side (iOS app) --> the sign_in api returns the access-token
2. Create a post from the client side using the access-token.

I managed to get the access-token using this code:

```
let parameters = [
        "email":"omar@omar.com",
        "password":"password"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/sign_in", parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in
            // get my access token and store it.
}
```

When I try to create a post(2nd part), here is what I did :

```
let headers = ["access-token":"<my-token-value>",
                   "token-type":   "Bearer",
                   "uid":"omar@omar.com"]

let parameters = [
        "title":"this is a title",
        "body":"this is a body"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:3000/api/posts", parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.response) // URL response
}
```

When printing the response, here is what I get:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe422f2b670> { URL: http://localhost:3000/api/posts } { status code: 401, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Length" = 37;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Thu, 03 Mar 2016 15:03:27 GMT";
Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26)";
"Set-Cookie" = "request_method=POST; path=/";
Vary = Origin;
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-Request-Id" = "82a88799-3fac-42e0-bd01-db5b7e24fcda";
"X-Runtime" = "0.045969";
"X-Xss-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} })
```

Also, on Rails server logs:

```
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
```

`Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)`

Does anyone know where the error is coming from?

Comment: Have you tried auth_token instead of access-token? My rails app with devise uses auth_token, I think by default

Comment: It didn't work.. it is access-token according to https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#token-header-format

Comment: Perhaps you should try intercepting your POST (with Fiddler, or similar) to see what headers are actually being sent to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Beside expecting the `access-token`, the `token-type` and the `uid`, my API was also expecting the `client` id in the headers. This `client` id is sent at the `sign_in` request response.